# Flex row occupying height even without the presence of content

Tags: css, flexbox, vuejs2, quasar-framework

I use vuejs and quasar framework, I'm customizing a third party component, there is a point where I have nested flex-rows, this is all defined by the inner classes of the quasar, so I can not control this directly so I'm overwriting some parts of the css .

My problem is that even when I have no content the flex-row is rendering a height, and this is not expected, since the row is empty. I need to know how to fix this.

Since some settings come from the quasar and I do not have access I will make available what the browser gives me data after rendering.

the tag with the problem in question is a div:

```
div{
  align-content: normal;
  align-items: normal;
  align-self: auto;
  alignment-baseline: auto;
  direction: ltr;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: auto;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  height: auto;
}
```

Apparently the height auto is generating this.

Comment: Generally `align-items: flex-start` will fix that, though you need to post a minimal code snippet as well, so we can see what is going on.

Comment: That is the problem, the css code that is causing this is internal to the quasar component I do not have access to.

Comment: Then how should we know how to fix what is wrong when we can't see it? ... Also, are you aware of that you can right click on the rendered result in the browser, and choose "Inspect". With that you might be able to get both markup and styles.

Comment: I added the code, if you need more data let me know, because most of this css already comes with the quasar framework components.

Comment: With that, all I can say is that for both `align-items: normal` and `align-self: auto`, those values are invalid and likely cause them to revert to their default, which is `stretch`, and that will cause an item to fill its parent whether it has content or not. Change both to `flex-start` ... Also, the value for `align-content: normal` is invalid, though this affect wrapped row items and won't apply for an empty flex container, still, it should likely also be set to `flex-start`.

Comment: The update is still not enough. We need a minimal _working_ code snippet reproducing the issue, so we can see what goes wrong.

Comment: The problem was not css, the problem is that this is a carousel component it loads the slides dynamically, to avoid overloads, I only load the ones being viewed and the others I leave a text with an H3 with a message of "loading. .. ", in short, the quasar component aligns all the slides inside a flex row, although the visible slides had no content the others had and so the size was increasing.